# Creating Tables in mysqli with timestamp

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have been making tables with a modified row which is time stamped.

```
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I am seeking to rename this as `bookedin`and timestamp the day of entry into the database.

i have looked on the net for a solution at sites like http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp

And cant seem to find a solution that works or is what i need.

I tried to edit it in the databse myself but with no luck. as you can tell im a extremity novice

Answer (score 0):

Instead of w3schools you really should use the actual MySQL documentations. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
 alter table tablename change `modified` `bookedin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Or maybe just

```
 alter table tablename change `modified` `bookedin` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT
 CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I think the on update may just be part of the timestamp datatype.  And, I think that altering the name of the table might cause all the rows to update their timestamp to the date you did it.  So you might want to make a copy of the table and try it out first.  I remember running into a problem like that once that made me switch from using TIMESTAMP to DATETIME.

Comment: will this give me the date as 21/02/2013?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Dates will all be stored in yyyy-mm-dd format by default, and you can use mysql date formatting functions to return the values formatted differently, if that's what you mean.